# What is this small field plant with a tuberous root?

Tags: identification, roots, perennials, wildflowers

This plant was collected in a field South-Central Europe. Assume the height of the photo is 20cm. These are all small herbaceous plants.

[image]

The ball next to it is the root. It has small bag-like accessories on it.

Comment: I would go with something from the Fabaceae   (pea family). I'll check my wild flowers of Europe when I get home. @quantomic any idea what the flower color is?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be [Corydalis yanhusuo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corydalis_yanhusuo). A flower would confirm. not native to the area it was collected, but as a commercialized plant that is not unusual. Compounds from the plant are used in medicine. Flower color ranges.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Shoot; #1 my guess is Alfalfa (I've got 3 other ideas...but meadow)? #6 is Stachys lanata, Woolly Lambs Ear.  #8 is a Daffodil #9 possibly Deer Fern.

Ugh, I don't care if I am wrong...#1 i a buggar!!  American Ground Nut?